# How can you change the block relation line colors in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to see if you can update the colors for each block relation line.  Similar to how [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) works.  Nothing is more annoying than tracking the same color line down.  As you can see in the pic they are all light gray.  I would like a couple of different colors... like grandparent = light green, parent light blue, child light red - repeat down.  Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the Bracket Pair Colorizer extension? It only highlights one line in color at a time?

Comment: No, you can only separately color the active indent guide with "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#fff8",
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#fff0",  Here I have all indent guides transparent except the active indentguide.  You will have to use some extension otherwise.

Comment: @AlexMyers when you're coding HTML or tagbased the bracket pair doesn't apply... unless there is a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the Bracket Pair Colorizer extension to support HTML by updating the `bracketPairColorizer.consecutivePairColors` setting.

Add the following to the configuration to support HTML as seen below.

- `["<", "</"]`
- `["<", "/>"]`

**settings.json:**

```
"bracketPairColorizer.consecutivePairColors": [
    "()",
    "[]",
    "{}",
    ["<", "</"],
    ["<", "/>"],
    [
        "Gold",
        "Orchid",
        "LightSkyBlue"
    ],
    "Red"
],
```

**Result:**

[image]